# Convert http text response to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

I want to convert the below text into a pandas dataframe. Is there a way I can use Python Pandas pre-built or in-built parser to convert? I can make a custom function for parsing but want to know if there is pre-built and/or fast solution.

In this example, the dataframe should result in two rows, one each of ABC & PQR

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "ABC",
      "Col1": "ABC_C1",
      "Col2": "ABC_C2"
    },
    {
      "ID": "PQR",
      "Col1": "PQR_C1",
      "Col2": "PQR_C2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've listed everything you need as tags. Use `json.loads` to get a dict from string

```
import json
import pandas as pd

d = json.loads('''{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "ABC",
      "Col1": "ABC_C1",
      "Col2": "ABC_C2"
    },
    {
      "ID": "PQR",
      "Col1": "PQR_C1",
      "Col2": "PQR_C2"
    }
  ]
}''')
df = pd.DataFrame(d['data'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    ID    Col1    Col2
0  ABC  ABC_C1  ABC_C2
1  PQR  PQR_C1  PQR_C2
```